# UISplitViewControllerDelegate - willHideViewController:... not sending a UIBarButtonItem?

Tags: iphone, uisplitviewcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

I've implemented the UISplitViewControllerDelegate and I'm trying to find why my code crashes when I rotate.

Right now I have my AppDelegate as the object that implements the delegate methods and then I have a protocol (`SubstitutableDetailViewController`) setup for my details views to handle the adding/removing of the UIBarButton item.

```
- (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController*)svc 
     willHideViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController 
          withBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem*)barButtonItem 
       forPopoverController:(UIPopoverController*)pc {

    // Keep references to the popover controller and the popover button, and tell the detail view controller to show the button.

    NSLog(@"barButtonItem class %@",[barButtonItem class]);

    [barButtonItem setTitle:[NSString stringWithString:@"Menu"]];
    self.popoverController = pc;
    self.rootPopoverButtonItem = barButtonItem;

    UIViewController <SubstitutableDetailViewController> *detailViewController = [splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];

    [detailViewController showRootPopoverButtonItem:rootPopoverButtonItem];
}
```

The issue here is that the log prints out 'barButtonItem class __NSCFArray'.

Why would the UIBarButtonItem be coming through as an array? This then throws an error because I'm trying to set the title of the "array".

```
-[__NSCFArray view]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x150510
```

Any ideas as to why it wouldn't be the right object?

And if I comment them out, it throws an error when I try to add this barButtonItem to the toolbar. Again, it isn't the write type of object.